# HTML entities in TextFlow

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript, entities, tlf

How can HTML entities be made to work with TextFlow (specifically TEXT_LAYOUT_FORMAT)?

> Example: ' is not converted into a single quote.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code with a description of what you're trying to do?  What exactly is throwing that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;
            import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;

            private const text:String = "&lt; &gt; &quot; &apos;";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:RichEditableText editable="false"
                        selectable="true"
                        textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT)}"
                        buttonMode="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%" />

</s:Application>
```